# NativeUIManager.getConstantsForViewManager('Text') threw an exception.Calling synchronous methods on native modules is not supported in Chrome aaa

Tags: react-native

I used react-native Element and my device show an Error to me in Debugger

`NativeUIManager.getConstantsForViewManager('Text') threw an exception.Calling synchronous methods on native modules is not supported in Chrome`

[image]

Comment: That's odd as today I also got this message on an app that was working fine a couple of days ago. The app is working. So to reproduce this error: Win 10, open app folder (React-Native) open a couple of windows command prompts, adb devices, adb reverse tcp:8081 tcp:8081 (using a real device) then npx react-native start in one and npx react-native run-android in other command window, d to get menu on phone and then debug. Opens tab in Brave browser and F12 to get dev tools. Reload app and see errors - App works fine after errors displayed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was on version 0.65.1   (look at package.json for your version)
I noticed a new version has been released on Oct 1 2021 so I upgraded:
https://www.reactnative.dev/blog/2021/10/01/version-066

npx react-native upgrade

https://reactnative.dev/docs/upgrading

I got all sorts of warnings and errors (what a surprise!! - that's sarcasm)

Anyhow I've restarted the app from scratch and the error has now disappeared.

(I'd make sure you have a backup (git/github) before upgrading perhaps)

Maybe this will help (and probably introduce a whole load of new issues :sigh )

Comment: Yes, downgrading the version to 0.64 no longer warning